# Proving an oblique asymptote

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} (\ln (e^{2x}-e^x+1) -2x)$$

It must be equal to zero, I tried L'hopital's rule after taking $2x$ common, but I got an answer of infinity.

Can you help me solve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{\ln(e^{2x} - e^x + 1) - 2x} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\ln(e^{2x} - e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{2x} - e^x + 1}{e^{2x}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - e^{-x} + e^{-2x}) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (\ln(e^{2x} - e^x + 1) - 2x) = \ln(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

I would say:

$\ln(e^{2x}-e^x+1)-2x = \ln( e^{2x}(1-e^{-x}+e^{-2x})-2x) = \\ = \ln e^{2x} + \ln(1-e^{-x}+e^{-2x})-2x = \cdots$